# How to write a Java program to create a HIVE UDF which performs MINUS operation?

Tags: java, hive, left-join, udf

Can anybody give me more insights on how to write a **JAVA program** to create a **UDF** which performs **MINUS** operation as MINUS is not supported in **HIVE** . 
This can be achieved with left outer join . **How do I start writing this UDF as a JAVA program ?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minus query in HIVE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760371/minus-query-in-hive)

Comment: @Salmonerd Please suggest me looking at the edited question n content

Comment: agreed, that would not be a duplicate