# How to identify deleted records in sql server while importing to hadoop using Sqoop

Tags: sql, sql-server, hadoop, hive, sqoop

While importing data from sql server or any RDBMS database to hadoop using Sqoop, we can get newly appended records or modified records using incremental append or last modified or some free form queries.

Is there anyway we can identify deleted records? Considering when record is deleted it will not exist in sql table.

One workaround is to load full table using Sqoop and compare with previous table in hive.

Is there any other best way to do?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not get deleted records using sqoop.

A better workaround could be:

Create a `boolean` field `status`(default `true`) in your SQL Server table.

Whenever you need to delete that record don't delete just update with marking status `false`.

If you are using `last-modified` increment import, you will get this changed data in HDFS.

Later *(after sqqop import)* you can delete all these records with status `false`.

Comment: Thanks dev. Source is another system, where we don't have control. So I think this approach is not suitable in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are syncing the entire partition or table then you can identify deleted records after sqoop import before merging them using full join with existing target partition or table. Records existing in target table/partition which do not exist in imported data are those deleted on source database since last sync.

Answer (score 0):

Incremental sqooping does not handle deleted records out of the box. There are two approach you may want to consider.

Please look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41380740/sqoop-incremental-import-how-it-handles-the-data-when-a-row-is-deleted-from-the/41623129#41623129).