# How to subtract two query result in hive

Tags: hive

I have tried this code in SQL it is working fine but in hive it is not working

```
select((select sum(price) from apart where construction_year=2020) - (select sum(price) from apart where construction_year=1990)) as difference_between_1990_and_2020;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minus query in HIVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760371/minus-query-in-hive)

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert them to subquery

```
select p20-p19 as difference_between_1990_and_2020
from 
(select((select sum(price) p20 from apart where construction_year=2020) rs20
join (select sum(price) p19 from apart where construction_year=1990) rs19 on 1=1
```